# Stream operator << for output is interpreted by compiler as binary operator << for bitwise shifting left?

Tags: c++

Attempting to get done with a simple drill from Bjarne Stroustrup book drives me naturally mad...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define smaller(a,b)    ((a)<(b)) ? (a) : (b)
#define larger(a,b)     ((a)<(b)) ? (a) : (b)

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    while (cin >> a >> b) {
        cout << "The smaller value is: " << smaller(a,b)
             << "\nThe larger value is: " << larger(a,b); 
    }
}
```

Of course, something went wrong, and guess what? Here:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -o un4 un4.cpp
un4.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
un4.cpp:13:17: error: invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘const char [23]’ to binary ‘operator<<’
              << "\nThe larger value is: " << larger(a,b); 
                 ^
```

Appreciate, if someone explains, what is the magic

Comment: the problem is macros and operator precendence.

Comment: out of curiosity: bjarne is really advertising the use of macros in his book? or is this just a negative example?

Comment: no. that's my initiative)

Comment: While I usually rail against parentheses (because beginners tend to use them as a shortcut to avoid learning precedence), with macros, the more parentheses the better. Well, sort of. But always put parentheses around each use of an argument (which these macros do) and always put parentheses around the entire replacement text (which fixes the problem here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are not functions, they are just parametrized text replacement. So you need to protect against parsing expressions with operator of different priorities. A very common pattern is to always parenthesized the full macro, as:

```
#define smaller(a,b)    ( ((a)<(b)) ? (a) : (b) )
#define larger(a,b)     ( ((a)<(b)) ? (a) : (b) )
```

-----EDIT-----

When you write `something << smaller(x,y) << anotherthing` the compiler just replace the **text** `smaller(x,y)` with its exact **text expansion** (+ macro parameters replacement), thus in your case it leads to:

```
something << ((x)<(y)) ? (x) : (y) << anotherthing
```

and this is not what you want, because `<<` has higher precedence than ternary `?:`, it means (with added parenthesis):

```
( something << ((x)<(y)) ) ? (x) : ( (y) << anotherthing )
```

and in this expression the problem is the sub-expression `(y) << anotherthing` which in your case is something like `3 << "foo"` which is not a correct expression.

After correcting the macro the example expression is expanded to:

```
something << ( ((x)<(y)) ? (x) : (y) ) << anotherthing
```

and evaluated as:

```
( something << ( ((x)<(y)) ? (x) : (y) ) ) << anotherthing
```

which is what you want.

Macros are really weird and your a encouraged not to use them.

Comment: fixing code the way you showed really did the trick, but I still have no idea, how unparenthesized ? and : makes the compiler think of << as of SHL, although I'm familiar with what is preprocessor and all the replacements. Anyway, thank you, from now I'll always parenthesize macros

Comment: oh.. I should have noticed, that it says int and const char[], not const char[] and int (int is left operand)